Getting “404 - Not found” when I call add comment to work item Azure DevOps API
I am setting up a ticketing system with ADO as the backend. I am using Power Automate to read emails and create a ticket (work item in ADO). I have described the whole flow below. I am stuck at Flow 2. I get “Not found” response when I call the add comment Azure DevOps API “_apis/wit/workitems/17854?api-version=7.0\”.
I appreciate any help you can provide to resolve this issue.
My Power Automate Flow
✅Flow1 - Create new ticket: If the subject has [SR], create a work item in Azure DevOps and save the attachment to the work item
✅a) Create a work item with the subject as title and body as the description
✅b) Save the attachment to Azure DevOps using post API
✅c) Relate the attachment to the newly created work item
❌Flow2 - Add comments to existing ticket: If the subject has [SR-XXXXX], add the email body as a comment. XXXXX stands for the work items id.
Flow 2 configuration:
Flow 2 configuration in power automate
Flow 2 raw input
Flow 2 raw input passed to the flow execution
Flow 3 output
404 - Not found
Appreciate your time and help 
I have validated the url and the work item id. Everything seems to be correct based on the API reference below.
Azure DevOps API Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

You are missing ProjectName at the front of your POST URL.

Thank you @SamNseir. That was it. As soon as I added /project_name, it worked. Here is the fixed URL
/project_name/_apis/wit/workItems/@{outputs('Get_Ticket_Id')}/comments?api-version=7.0-preview.3

POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{workItemId}/comments?api-version=7.0-preview.3

The Comments - Add REST API needs the project name in the Request URI. In your screenshot, the project name is not provided. You should add the project name in the Relative URI.


Thank you @miao-tian-msft. That was it. As soon as I added /project_name, it worked. Here is the fixed URL
/project_name/_apis/wit/workItems/@{outputs('Get_Ticket_Id')}/comments?api-version=7.0-preview.3

Hi @PraveenAnuraj, glad to hear that the issue is solved. The Comments - Add REST API needs the project name in the Request URI.  Thanks for your update and happy coding!
